# Why is stringstream only reading the first digit in my integer? How do I make it so it only moves on at a blank space?

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream

Relevant code is as follows:

```
string output;
char letter, number, symbol;

cout << "Input a letter, number, and a symbol separated by a space: ";
getline(cin, output);
istringstream(output) >> letter >> number >> symbol;
```

However, if I type in a multiple digit number, it only saves the first one, and then whatever is assigned to symbol is.. not correct.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it so it only stops reading when it hits a blank space?

Comment: You store the number as a `char`, which is a unique character, no multiple digits won't work. You can try to change it to `int`. And what do you mean by "symbol"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`letter`, `number`, and `symbol` are all defined as `char` type so you're only going to get one character into each variable. Try making `number` an `int` instead.